# Unable to match using regex in pandas

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi i have a dataframe as below, for which i need to match a number followed by its unit and return only the number

I have units like, ml, gallon, l etc

Input:

```
   text                                       
   1234567-CAR WA GK5 9x78x90 12L              

   3456789 TOP-L BD3 195x169x62 TopL
```

Expected output:

```
   text                                        extract              Return
   1234567-CAR WA GK5 9x78x90 12L              12L                  12

   3456789 TOP-L BD3 195x169x62 TopL           -                    -
```

code:

```
  def names(header):

       if re.search('([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*|)(\s|[a-z]*)(\s|[a-z]*)(\s|)ml)',header):
          pos_start = re.search('([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*|)(\s|[a-z]*)(\s|[a-z]*)(\s|)ml)', header).start()
          pos_end = re.search('([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*|)(\s|[a-z]*)(\s|[a-z]*)(\s|)ml)', header).end()
          return header[pos_start:pos_end]  


       elif re.search('((\d*)l)',header):
          pos_start = re.search('((\d*)l)', header).start()
          pos_end = re.search('((\d*)l)', header).end()
          return header[pos_start:pos_end] 


 def measure(val):

    ml=['ml','ML','mL','Ml']
    l=['l','L','Lt','lt']


    if any(x in val for x in ml):
        return float(re.findall('(\d+\.\d+|\d+)', val)[0])

    if any(x in val for x in l):
        return float(re.findall('(\d+\.\d+|\d+)', val)[0])*1000   

df_result = pd.concat([df['A'],df['text'],df['B'],df['text'].apply(names),(df['text'].apply(names)).dropna().apply(measure)],axis=1)
```

Error:

```
    ---> 22 return float(re.findall('(\d+\.\d+|\d+)', val)[0])*1000



         IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Is the 'extract' item you want always at the end , begins with numbers & if yes, how many numbers?

Comment: how did you apply your function on your dataframe?

Comment: @SH-SF it can be 1 digit or 2 or 3 or even decimal. For example, 2l, 3.5L, 5liters etc

Comment: @Datanovice   df_result = pd.concat([df['A'],df['text'],df['B'],df['text'].apply(names),(df['text'].apply(names)).dropna().apply(measure)],axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
def measure(val):
    header_l = header.lower()
    m = re.match(`(\d+(\.\d+)?)(m?[illi]*l[iters]*)`, header_l, re.IGNORECASE)
    if m:
        as_ml = 1 if m.group(3).startswith('m') else 1000
        return float(m.group(1)) * as_ml
    return None
```

Comment: I just need for "l" cases

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you

```
df['extract']= [val[-1] for val in df['text'].str.split()]
df['Return']=df['extract'].str.extract(r'(\d+)').fillna('-')
print(df)

                               text     extract     Return
0   1234567-CAR WA GK5 9x78x90 12L      12L          12
1   3456789 TOP-L BD3 195x169x62 TopL   TopL         -
```